# Is there shorthand in Java to call a bunch of class methods in a row?

Tags: java

Hey, all! New java programmer here, trying to learn good style. Is there a shorthand to call a bunch of class methods in a row? Like say I wanted to do:

```
Dog gus = new Dog();

gus.fetch();
gus.sit();
gus.lieDown();
gus.rollOver();
```

In VBasic, for example, I could enclose it all in a With block. Does java have anything similar?

Comment: No, but this can be done using the builder pattern. Basically make all those methods `return this` and chain them. Can't do much about the design choices of external APIs though.

Comment: Damn. That's an interesting workaround though @Meguy26, unfortunately it's not really clean for what I'd want to use it for. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of options. I think you want patterns. You could build a helper method that calls all of the methods. Your other option is to have your methods return the parent object.

```
public Dog fetch(){
    //Do stuff for fetch
    return this;
}
public Dog sit(){
    //Do stuff for sit
    return this;
}
public Dog lieDown(){
    //Do stuff for lieDown
    return this;
}
public Dog rollOver(){
    //Do stuff for rollOver
    return this;
}
```

Then you can call them like:

```
Dog gus = new Dog();

gus.fetch().sit().lieDown().rollOver();
```

Comment: Well formulated answer! I think a helper method would probably be the way to go but in this case it's little situational which methods would be called, so it would probably be overkill to write that all up. Thanks!